# grep string between two patterns in a column

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a table with 2 columns separated by a tab, and I would like to parse the second column. This is an example of one line of my table:

```
Solyc00g005080.1.1  query_length=98;subject_id=D3WD45;Name=D3WD45_XIMAM;Note=Putative RF2 protein OS-Ximenia americana GN-ycf2 PE-3 SV-1;subject_length=2285;subject_start=1509;subject_end=1588;e-value=  3e-38;identities=77/80 (96%25);gaps=0;positives=79/80 (98%25);length_coverage=80/98 (81.63%25)
```

The output that I want:

```
Solyc00g005080.1.1  Putative RF2 protein OS-Ximenia americana GN-ycf2 PE-3 SV-1
```

I have tried several combinations with grep and awk but I can't find the correct way. I need a command with `awk/sed/grep` to parse the string after `Note=` and `;` in the second column.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.  Chances are you've got 90% of it right.

Comment: You need basic `sub()` here.  People work to write manuals so that one would read those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*\t).*Note=([^;]+).*/\1\2/' file
olyc00g005080.1.1       Putative RF2 protein OS-Ximenia americana GN-ycf2 PE-3 SV-1
```

Comment: +1 for clear and simple regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this GNU `sed` command,

```
sed -r 's/^(.*)( +).*Note=(.*);.*;.*;.*;.*;.*;.*;.*;.*/\1\2\3/g' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'Solyc00g005080.1.1             query_length=98;subject_id=D3WD45;Name=D3WD45_XIMAM;Note=Putative RF2 protein OS-Ximenia americana GN-ycf2 PE-3 SV-1;subject_length=2285;subject_start=1509;subject_end=1588;e-value=  3e-38;identities=77/80 (96%25);gaps=0;positives=79/80 (98%25);length_coverage=80/98 (81.63%25)' | sed -r 's/^(.*)( +).*Note=(.*);.*;.*;.*;.*;.*;.*;.*;.*/\1\2\3/g'
Solyc00g005080.1.1             Putative RF2 protein OS-Ximenia americana GN-ycf2 PE-3 SV-1
```